# Show progress indicators in Mail 6 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Apple seems to have taken the brilliant decision of not showing progress indicators when you are checking for new emails. This is annoying, as you get 0 feedback when you press the "Get new messages" button.

Is there any way of getting Mail to still show the "checking for email" progress indicators?

Answer (score 1):

I also found this problem pretty disturbing.

I didn't find a solution to bring the indicator back yet, but for having some kind of feedback I am using the activity window:

You can find it in the menubar: Windows --> Activity
or you can press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score -3):

Click the arrow at the bottom of the sidebar in the main window to show the 'Mail Activity" indicators.

Comment: This does not show "checking for email" activities.